# Convert an array to xml with customized element tag name

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell script.

```
$load = @(@(1, 2), @(3))
$Load | % { "[$_]" }
$Date = Get-Date "2012-01-01"
$xml = $Load | ConvertTo-Xml -NoTypeInformation
$xml.OuterXml
```

The code generates the following result.

```
[1 2]
[3]
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property>1</Property>
    <Property>2</Property>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <Property>3</Property>
   </Object>
 </Objects>
```

However I want to be able to specify the the xml element name and add an extra `Date`(constant) element. Is it an easy way to do it?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Groups>
  <Group>
    <Item><ID>1</ID><Date>2012-01-01</Date></Item>
    <Item><ID>2</ID><Date>2012-01-01</Date></Item>
   </Group>
  <Group>
    <Item><ID>3</ID><Date>2012-01-01</Date></Item>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

I tried the following "new object" approach but the result is very verbose and not what I want.

```
$load = @(@(1, 2), @(3))
$Load | % { "[$_]" }
$Date = Get-Date "2012-01-01"
$xml = $Load | 
    % { 
        @(, @{ ID = $_; Date = $Date }) 
    } | 
    ConvertTo-Xml -NoTypeInformation 
$xml.OuterXml
```

Comment: Check out my answer on this [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751230/append-data-into-existing-xml-file-via-powershell/13751693#13751693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. `Select-Xml`
2. Plain old string concatenation